# Select Option Value remains the same after submit form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a select option like this:

```
<select class="form-control dropdown" name="enable_pass_through"
        id="enable_pass_through" value="${requestScope.enable_pass_through}">
       <option value="true">true</option>
       <option value="false">false</option>
</select>
```

Whenever I select "false" for example and when I click on my submit button, the page refresh and it still shows "true" rather than the selected "false" option. Even though my data has been updated to "false". I do not know how to solve this issue, please assist me. This is also under a POST method

Comment: Did you update the markup of the page on the server?

Comment: @Teemu What do you mean? From the Java file side? If you are referring to that, then yes I did

Comment: Yes, otherwise the original page will be loaded.

Comment: @Teemu what I did was first to get selected data and update the file. Afterwards I did request.setAttribute(name,value)